# Why don't Thor's goats appear in the MCU?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, thor-marvel, animals, mythology

If I remember correctly, Thor in Nordic mythology has his hammer and his two flying goats, which can recreate themselves from just a single bone. Why doesn't he have the goats in the Marvel movies? Is it because it would be too silly for Thor to have it? I'm from Denmark and had Nordic mythology in school.

Comment: I'm not sure there will really be an answer as to why he doesn't have goats in the Marvel movies.

Comment: Thor in the MCU is based on the character Thor from the Marvel comics, which is based on Thor from Norse mythology. Does he even have the goats in the comics?

Comment: @AnthonyGrist No.  Norse Thor cannot fly either (thats why he has his goats). While Marvel Thor & that entire universe is fairly similar to Norse thor... it is adapted ... imagine if there was a Marvel comic/film about Heimdall sleeping with old people (Norse genesis )

Comment: Worth noting is that Thor in Marvel Comics (T:MC) is not Thor, the God of Thunder from Norse Mythology (T:NM). T:MC is a person that is worthy of wielding Mjolnir, and is granted powers by said hammer. Thor in Marvel Cinematic Universe (T:MCU), however, IS the God of Thunder. T:MCU is based more on the T:NM than T:MC, but he is still not an exact adaptation (nor is anything else that MCU has adapted from the Norse Mythology).

Comment: I am reopening the question. Thor indeed DOES have his goats in the Marvel Universe.

Answer (score 18):

#### Thor Odinson's goats do appear in the comic Marvel Universe. Recently when he lost access to Mjolnir (which in the Marvel Universe is how he gains the power of flight) he was forced to return to his chariot and his two magical goats: [Toothgnasher and Toothgrinder](http://comicvine.gamespot.com/toothgnasher/4005-22293/).

- They do not appear in the Marvel Cinematic Universe because it isn't necessary that they do. Thor can fly with Mjolnir and can get goat meat at any decent restaurant in New York City.

[image]

- They even have their legendary power of immortality, allowing them to be eaten and reborn as long as no bones are broken. They are also superhumanly strong, able to damage the Mjolnir despite it being made of uru metal and Odin's enchantments.
- Their first appearance was in Thor Annual #5 (September, 1976)

[image]

[image]

- **See Also:** [How Does Thor's Flight Work?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/26472/2765)

Comment: The comics present lots of (helpfully numbered) universes, there is no "Marvel Universe".

Comment: Do I know you? Did you just tell me there is no Marvel Universe? Perhaps you are new here but the convention of numbering universes is a relatively new one. I have been reading comics before numbering universes was considered trendy and the Multiple Worlds Theory was something found in a Roger Zelazny novel. It is generally understood, unless a particular universe is designated, any reference to the "Marvel Universe" is defaulted to Earth-616 and the Marvel Cinematic Universe as Earth-199999. The terminology is essentially correct.

Comment: I can tell from your tone you can't be reasoned with, but I was just pointing out you could be more precise regarding in which continuities the goats do and do not appear.

Comment: 1. "Thor Odinson's goats do appear in the comic Marvel Universe." 2. "They do not appear in the Marvel Cinematic Universe because it isn't necessary that they do. Thor can fly with Mjolnir and can get goat meat at any decent restaurant in New York City." First sentence. Second sentence. Unreasonably direct.

Comment: The usage of "Marvel Universe" persists to this day. In recent issues of "Spider Women," Earth-616 is referred to as The Marvel Universe, while Earth-65 is referred to as such.

Answer (score 9):

#### Thor’s goats have finally made their MCU debut

But they are not from Asgard, as in Norse mythology. They are from a planet called Indigarr, which Thor visited in *Thor: Love and Thunder*. There, he received two giant goats as a gift from King Yakan, who was grateful for Thor’s help in defending Indigarr from invaders.

[image: Thor's goats]

[image: one of Thor's goats screaming]

Thor thought they were beautiful, and Korg remarked that they scream quite a lot.